# Convertible note: instead of equity, convertible into a product. Tax consequence for the issuer?

Tags: united-states, loans, debt

if a US issuer sells a convertible note which isn't convertible into equity, but convertible into a quantity of product the issuer makes, what are the tax consequences upon conversion?

When the issuer pays off the debt via conversion into the quantity of the product that the creditor now owns, is this revenue for the issuer? Or is it a non taxable transaction when structured this way, for the issuer. I'm not concerned about the creditor in this case.

And yes, eventually I'll ask a tax lawyer, because its so practical to you guys that I would pay $1000 an hour for hypothetical questions.

Insight appreciated!

Comment: By "note" do you mean a debt instrument? Meaning the note can either be redeemed for the product or for the principal amount?

Comment: @DStanley yes correct

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange idea, but let's make it concrete.  It is a $1,000 note to a farmer.  At any time it can be converted into a fixed quantity of wheat at a predetermined price per bushel.

This is not a "convertible" so much as bond with a weird put agreement.  The bond would only be exercised when the price of wheat is well above the conversion price and even then, only if interest rates had not made the bond too valuable to convert.

The character of the transaction is that this is debt at the time of issuance.  If the contract were exercised, then notes payable would be debited, and the wheat would be credited.  You would also have $1,000 in revenue and an appropriate reduction in inventory.

As this is a barter transaction, you could think of it as a $1,000 crediting of cash and a $1,000 debiting of cash in the middle of the transaction if it helps you think about it.

If the contract were naked or in an industry with either regulatory or unusual accounting rules, then there could be additional transactions or accounting processes that would need to happen.  Also, if GAAP obtained, then derivative accounting may also apply.  This should not be the case if the firm regularly makes this product because a derivative fulfilled from ordinary operations does not require derivative accounting, but if it is an incidental product or it ceases engaging in the production of it, then derivative accounting would apply.

Comment: Interesting analogy, but one difference between a put option and a convertible note is that the note can be redeemed for the notional amount at the end - with the option the premium is a sunk cost.

Comment: It's still there and still sunk. It is the present value of the expected reduced  interest from the presence of the right.

Comment: why would you call it a put and not a call?

Comment: Because it is a right to give back the note.  It could be viewed as a simultaneous put and call in that the note is put with a call on the product.  The call component seems less credible because there are non - price reasons to put the note such as a change in bankruptcy risk.  You may be willing to take the product at an adverse price to salvage the position.